# What is the most optimal way to obtain a value from a thread and use it in the main thread right after the thread resolves?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm making an android app that scrapes a website and puts the scraped information into a list. The issue that I have is that I have to block the main thread for some time until the scraping is done.

```
int opt = 0;
String phone = "";

...

adAdapter = new AdAdapter(new AdDiffer(), ad ->
{

    new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(ad.getUrl()).get();

                    Element elem = doc.getElementsByClass("hGYViW").get(0).....

                    Elements e = null;

                    try
                    {
                        e = elem.getElementsByTag("div").get(0).getElementsByClass("hMvGEj");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) {}

                    if(e.size() != 0)
                    {
                        phone = elem.getElementsByTag("div").get(0).getElementsByClass("hMvGEj").get(0).getElementsByTag("a").get(0).html();
                        opt = 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        opt = 1;
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }).start();

        while(opt == 0) {}

        if(opt == 2)
        {
            opt = 0;
            phone = "";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            opt = 0;
            phone = "";
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(ad.getUrl())));
        }
        return null;
});
```

Is there a way to make this work without having to block the main thread?

Comment: "Is there a way to make this work without having to block the main thread?" -- use reactive APIs (`LiveData`, RxJava, Kotlin coroutines, `Future`, etc.). See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/threading) or any decent modern book or course on Android app development.

Comment: You can use an `interface` to communicate between threads. Very similar to on how `setOnClickListener()` works. Use a handler for passing data to main thread -- recommended. At the end of the day, it all depends on how you code your program.